# How to use on save action for file type in vim?

Tags: vim

I am using [vim-jsbeautify](https://github.com/maksimr/vim-jsbeautify) and I think it is awesome.

However I would like to add the reformatting on the save action. At the moment I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> each time I want to reformat. I tried

```
 autocmd FileType html AutoFormatBuffer :call HtmlBeautify()<cr>
```

but somehow that command is wrong, could someone please clarify?

#### Update

Just as [@Ingo Karkat](https://superuser.com/users/117820/ingo-karkat) mentioned. For this case create a file in

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/html/main.vim
```

and add the line into the file

```
autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call HtmlBeautify()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your command (`call HtmlBeautify()`) needs to be triggered before saving. `:help autocmd-events` lists all available ones; `BufWritePre` is the one you want. The `{cmd}` for `:autocmd` is an *Ex command*, so you can drop the `:` (that switches from *normal mode* to *command-line mode*), and have to drop the `<CR>` (this is for mappings only):

```
autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call HtmlBeautify()
```

Now, you want that trigger installed for every opened HTML file. The way you tried this is by using another `:autocmd` on the `FileType` event:

```
autocmd FileType html autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call HtmlBeautify()
```

But this is what *filetype plugins are for*:

I would recommend putting any settings, mappings, and filetype-specific autocmds (such as this) into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_whatever.vim` (or `{filetype}/whatever.vim`; cp. `:help ftplugin-name`) instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though.

Comment: thanks, Ingo. Your advice was very good and I also liked your best practice comment.